# What ages am I allowed to ask about here?

Tags: support

The help center say that this is on topic:

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor
> - Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher
> - Inner workings of research departments
> - Requirements and expectations of academicians
> - University-level pedagogy

I may be wrong, but I think that these are phrases that are used in the USA. What ages / years am I allowed to ask about if I live in the UK?

For example, I'm in Y11. I'm taking my GCSEs, and next year I start studying for my A Levels. Two years after that I go to university:

```
2015 - GCSEs (final year)
2016 - A Levels (First year)
2017 - A Levels (Final year)
2018 - University (or Gap year)
2019 - University
2020 - University
2021 - In severe debt and unemployed because of irresponsible money lending.
```

At what point am I allowed to ask questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anybody is allowed to participate in our community by asking and answering questions. The issue is really when will you have questions that are on topic. The term graduate student typically refers to a student who already holds a bachelors degree and is studying for a masters of doctoral degree. In the UK, these students are generally referred to as post-graduate students.

From you time line, you would graduate in 2020 with a bachelors degree. If you then entered a masters or doctoral program in 2021, you would begin experiencing things that would be on topic here. Technically, as you are preparing for a post graduate program (e.g., applying and choosing a course and modules at university), you might have some questions that are on topic here.